# how do get response of "GET / " request which is passed using popen communicate with underlying openssl

Tags: get, openssl, subprocess, head

I'm newbie to subprocess module - I would like to use openssl commands to connect with secure server url(for eg : wikipedia) in this case, I could able to connect with web-server and handshake is success.

But while requesting for GET / or HEAD request, i'm unable to receive or process the output.

**Obtained output :**

SSL handshake has read 3708 bytes and written 405 bytes
Verification: OK
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)

```py
import time
import subprocess

cmd ="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\openssl.exe s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443"
popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
input1 = "echo -en HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.wikipedia.org\r\n\r\n"
(test_stdout,test_stderr)= popen.communicate(input=input1)
popen.wait()
print(test_stdout)
print(f"return value of popen %r "% popen.returncode)
popen.terminate()
```

**Updated code with openssl -quiet or -ign_eof:**

```py
cmd1 ="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\openssl.exe s_client -connect www.wikipedia.org:443 -servername www.wikipedia.org -ign_eof"

popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd3,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
input1 ="echo HEAD / HTTP /1.1\r\nHost: www.wikipedia.org\r\n"
print(input1)
(test_stdout,test_stderr)= popen.communicate(input=input1)
print("value of popen")
print(test_stdout)
print(f"return value of popen %r "% popen.returncode)
popen.terminate()
```

Please find different results :
1/ Left - results of Py charm
2/ Right - results of executing in openssl s_client command
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the script is ok and does what it is supposed to do:
It gives you the server ciphers and TLS config.

But judging by your text, what you *want* to do is something different:
You want to send some HTTP requests and display their responses.

In order to do that, you will have to replace your `cmd` with some `curl https://www.wikipedia.org` or `wget -O- https://www.wikipedia.org` and feed that into your *subprocess.Popen* command, instead of the *openssl* cmd.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In my project, i have to do handshake with different ciphersuites using PSK - so i have to use "OPENSSL" as the only option available. Upon successful handshake, I have to fetch GET or do POST Methods

Comment: I have tried by changing the command to cmd ="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\openssl.exe s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443 -quiet " this quiet option helped me to fetch the results. But then, i got strange results that is HTTP/1.0 400 Invalid HTTP Request. Whereas if you see the input1 - request is mentioned as HEAD HTTP/1.1 - Can anyone please respond or correcting the code would help me a lot

Comment: ok, so you received a successful response with a HEAD request, on the right side. One thing that seems wrong on the left side is that you have a space between HTTP and /1.1. It should be `GET / HTTP/1.1` (without the space)

Comment: - Thanks a good finding. so i have updated the command as follows :   input1=("echo -en HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.wikipedia.org\r\n\r\n") but still i m getting output  as HTTP/1.0 400 Invalid HTTP Request.  I'm still trying to figure out the issue - where it goes wrong